# Как превратить кортеж (со строками) в одну строку и поменять внутри слова

Tags: python-3.x

Дан кортеж, который содержит в себе несколько строк, например: ('right', rightleft', 'left', 'stop'). 
Нужно в итоге получить одну строку и чтобы все 'right', были заменены на 'left'. Примерно так: 'left, leftleft, left, stop'

```
def Aс (*phrases) :
    k = str(phrases)
    t = k.replace('right', 'left') # вот на этом я застрял
    print(t)
```

Comment: убрать вторую строку, а третью заменить на `t=', '.join(*phrases).replace('right', 'left')`. Не оно?

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

Comment: приводите полностью ваш код, что передаётся в функцию

Comment: Все ясно. Если вводить в функцию кортеж в двойных скобках (()), то надо убирать - * с phrase. Тогда все работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кортеж и строки являются неизменяемыми объектами в Питоне. Единственный способ "изменить" неизменяемый объект—это создать новый.

Чтобы заменить `'right'` подстроки на `'left'`:

```
phrases = tuple(s.replace('right', 'left') for s in phrases)
```

Чтобы заменить только целые строки:

```
phrases = tuple('left' if s == 'right' else s for s in phrases)
```

Чтобы напечатать строки через запятую:

```
print(*phrases, sep=',')
```

Если нужна строка:

```
text = ','.join(phrases)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def A(phrases) :
    return(','.join(phrases).replace('right', 'left'))
```